# Using random number creating small sub files from a large file in python

Tags: python

I have a file which contains suppose `m` rows, which has `n` comma separated values. Now I want to divide this into say `x` sub files. Suppose for an example say `m=21`, `n=4` and `x=5`. And let's say my `file(original.data)` looks like below:

```
11,12,13,14
15,16,17,18
19,20,21,22
23,24,25,26
27,28,29,30
31,32,33,34
35,36,37,38
39,40,41,42
43,44,45,46
47,48,48,50
51,52,53,54
55,56,57,58
59,60,61,62
63,64,65,66
67,68,69,70
71,72,73,74
75,76,77,78
79,80,81,82
83,84,85,86
87,88,89,90
91,92,93,94
```

Now I want to generate `m(=21)` random numbers starting from `0` to `m-1`, in this case from 0 to 20. Suppose the 1st generated random number is : `17`, this will say about in which sub file the 1st row of the above `original.data` will go. The first row will go to the `17 mod 5` that is 2nd number sub file(`subfile_1`), where 5 is the number of total sub files. Like that if the 2nd generated random number is : `14` then the 2nd row of the above `original.data` will go to the `14 mod 5` = 4th sub file(`subfile_3`) and so on. If the same random number is generated more than once then that will be ignored (As I need unique random numbers from 0 to 20 in this case).

That's how I want to create `5` sub files say- `subfile_0`,`subfile_1`...`subfile_4`. In this case `subfile_0` will hold `5 rows` and the rest 4 sub files will hold `4 rows`. Along with that I want to create `5` remaining data files as well say `remaining_0`,`remaining_1`...`remaining_4`, where `remaining_0` holds the rows remaining in `original.data` after removing the rows of `subfile_0`. So `remaining_0` will hold `16 rows` and the rest 4 `remaining` files will hold `17 rows`.

One more thing, I want to have the same sequence in which the 1st 21 random numbers were generated (pseudo random number). By that I wanted to mean if I run the program say 10 times then it should produce the same result every time.

Can anyone help me with this please! I am new to python. It will be a great help.

Comment: This sounds like an extremely specific problem, is this homework?

Comment: No no, I am doing an ML problem. Where I am trying to do a separate kind of test and train fold. I just don't want to use the module from sklearn as it is doing the shuffle each and every time. But I want to keep that thing fixed every time I run and that's why trying to think of a new algo to do the n-fold. You can say in above case `x` is nothing but the number of folds and `sub files` are the `test` files and `remaining` are the `train` files. I am just curious about this, but as I don't know python properly so unable to figure out how to do hence asked for the help.

Comment: This looks like an incredibly easy thing to code with very convoluted rules. If you break it down into steps, then it looks like you only need a few basic skills. "how to create a file", "how to pick a random number", "how to do a for loop", etc. If you follow a beginners tutorial, you'll probably be able solve this yourself before an answer is posted. If it comes across as rude I'm not meaning it that way, it just seems like the only reason you can't do it is because you've not broken it into steps.

Comment: @Peter I was trying a lot for the whole day when this idea came in my mind, but somehow I was not quite able to do it due to my lack of knowledge in programming domain. Can you help me out please! I am just curious to know whether or not this algorithm will work fine!

Comment: My point is that the rules are complicated enough that it would take quite a bit of effort to fully understand what's needed, but the actual code behind will be very simple. If you break it down into steps, you can say "ok for step 1 I need to generate a random number", "for step 4 I need to get the modulus of this", "for step 9 I need to create a file", etc. That should be very easy to do even as a beginner.

Comment: @Peter Okay I am trying my best. Please help me out if  I am unable to get the proper output for the above problem. As I am literally very curious to know whether or not the idea of this algorithm will work fine!

Comment: better get list with 21 numbers and shuffle it - numbers will not repeate. `a = list(range(21))` `random.shuffle(a)`, and if you use `random.seed(0)` at start then it will always generate the same order. you can use `seed()` with different value but always with the same - to get the same result.

Comment: @furas I was trying to do `import random
print(random.sample(range(21), 21))` , How can I make sure in this case every time it will generate the same random numbers!

Comment: as I said before: you have to use `random.seed(0)` at start to get the same result

Comment: @furas yes I am getting the same results.

Comment: frankly I don't understand why you need so complex method - I would first shuffle all lines and later write first 5 lines in first file, next 4 lines in second file, etc.. But all depends if you need to know where lines were moved.

Comment: @furas is there any way to keep those shuffles remain in same order each time I run them? Then it will do. My main motive is to have the same shuffle each time I run the code! For this purpose I am unable to use the sklearn's k fold method as each time it shuffles and my ordering gets changed.

Comment: as I said before: always use `random.seed(0)` and you get the same order

Comment: I never tested it but if `sklearn's k fold` uses standard module `random` then using `random.seed(0)` should always gives the same result from `sklearn's k fold`. And if `sklearn's k fold` use `numpy.random` then you could try with `numpy.random.seed(0)`

Comment: Can you please write this part of the code considering my `original.data` file. Which can have any number of columns and rows. It will be a good help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python uses `"pseudo"` generator for random numbers.

If you always use `random.seed()`  with the same value - i.e `0` - then you always get the same random numbers, or values in the same order.

And if someone else will use the same number in `random.seed()` then he/she should also get the same results.

```
import random

random.seed(0)

print(random.sample(range(21), 21))
```

gives me always

```
[12, 13, 1, 8, 16, 15, 6, 20, 4, 7, 5, 9, 3, 2, 11, 18, 0, 14, 17, 19, 10]
```

or

```
import random

random.seed(0)

a = list(range(21))
random.shuffle(a)
print(a)
```

gives me always

```
[10, 19, 17, 14, 0, 18, 11, 2, 3, 9, 5, 7, 4, 20, 6, 15, 16, 8, 1, 13, 12]
```

---

The same is with module `numpy.random` and `numpy.random.seed()`

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)

np.random.randint(0, 21, (3,3))
```

gives me always

```
array([[12, 15,  0],
       [ 3,  3,  7],
       [ 9, 19, 18]])
```

---

This is example which uses your idea to split data.

I uses `io.StringIO` only to simulate file in memory.

```
text = '''11,12,13,14
15,16,17,18
19,20,21,22
23,24,25,26
27,28,29,30
31,32,33,34
35,36,37,38
39,40,41,42
43,44,45,46
47,48,48,50
51,52,53,54
55,56,57,58
59,60,61,62
63,64,65,66
67,68,69,70
71,72,73,74
75,76,77,78
79,80,81,82
83,84,85,86
87,88,89,90
91,92,93,94
'''

import io
import random

random.seed(0)

f = io.StringIO(text)
lines = f.readlines()

#m = 21
m = len(lines)
n = 5

random_numbers = list(range(m))
random.shuffle(random_numbers)

for idx, (line, number) in enumerate(zip(lines, random_numbers), 1):
    line = line.strip()
    print(f'line: {idx:2} | {line} | random: {number:2} | file: {number % n}')
```

It gives me always

```
line:  1 | 11,12,13,14 | random: 10 | file: 0
line:  2 | 15,16,17,18 | random: 19 | file: 4
line:  3 | 19,20,21,22 | random: 17 | file: 2
line:  4 | 23,24,25,26 | random: 14 | file: 4
line:  5 | 27,28,29,30 | random:  0 | file: 0
line:  6 | 31,32,33,34 | random: 18 | file: 3
line:  7 | 35,36,37,38 | random: 11 | file: 1
line:  8 | 39,40,41,42 | random:  2 | file: 2
line:  9 | 43,44,45,46 | random:  3 | file: 3
line: 10 | 47,48,48,50 | random:  9 | file: 4
line: 11 | 51,52,53,54 | random:  5 | file: 0
line: 12 | 55,56,57,58 | random:  7 | file: 2
line: 13 | 59,60,61,62 | random:  4 | file: 4
line: 14 | 63,64,65,66 | random: 20 | file: 0
line: 15 | 67,68,69,70 | random:  6 | file: 1
line: 16 | 71,72,73,74 | random: 15 | file: 0
line: 17 | 75,76,77,78 | random: 16 | file: 1
line: 18 | 79,80,81,82 | random:  8 | file: 3
line: 19 | 83,84,85,86 | random:  1 | file: 1
line: 20 | 87,88,89,90 | random: 13 | file: 3
line: 21 | 91,92,93,94 | random: 12 | file: 2
```

---

**EDIT:**

You said you want to use `sklearn k-fold`

If you use `np.random.seed(0)` then it will create the same result (even with `shuffle=True`)

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

X = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [3, 4]])
y = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])

np.random.seed(0)
kf = KFold(n_splits=2, shuffle=True)

for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):
    print("TRAIN INDEX:", train_index, "TEST INDEX:", test_index)
```

It gives me always

```
TRAIN INDEX: [0 1] TEST INDEX: [2 3]
TRAIN INDEX: [2 3] TEST INDEX: [0 1]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understood the concept properly.